# How I get all the images from a perticular folder(iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm new on iPhone Dev. I need to show all image from a particular folder on gridview but I don't know how to.

Advice me please.Thank you
Ps.sorry for bad english

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure about the grid view part. But this will help you list the images.

```
    NSString *documents = [@"~/Documents/gallery" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:documents];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *tString;
    while ((tString = [direnum nextObject] ))
    {
        if ([tString hasSuffix:@".jpg"]) 
        {
            NSString *fileAbsPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documents,tString];
            //Do something with the file
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will get all files from a particular folder. You can replace `NSCachesDirectory` with `NSDocumentDirectory`.

```
- (NSArray *)getAllFilesfromAFolder:(NSString *)folderName
{
    NSString *stringPath = nil;
    if(folderName)
        stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
    else
        stringPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:stringPath  error:nil];
    return filePathsArray;
}
```